# How to declare a class function in header file in cpp file?

Tags: c++, class

For example in the following code:

```
class mixedFraction {
    public:
        mixedFraction();    //constructor
        void add(mixedFraction f);     //The functoin I want to define in cpp file
}
```

I know that to declare constructor in cpp is

```
<class name> :: <constructor name>(<type> <name>, ...);
```

But I try the samething with function it is wrong

```
mixedFraction::void add(mixedFraction f);
```

How can I do to make it correct?

Comment: `void mixedFraction::add(mixedFraction f);`

Comment: Ok, got it , thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the return type before the class name:

```
void mixedFraction::add (mixedFraction f) {
     //...
}
```

This kind of thing should be covered in your introductory book. If you don't have one I'd recommend buying/renting/stealing one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I know this is fundamental, but our teacher hasn't taught us class yet, and there is homework about class. And we don't have a textbook, so... Anyway, thanks.